# Go - correct usage of multipart Part.Read

Tags: go

I've been trying to use multipart.Part to help read very large file uploads (>20GB) from HTTP - so I've written the below code which seems to work nicely:

```golang
func ReceiveMultipartRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mediatype, p, err := mime.ParseMediaType(r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    if err != nil {
       //...
    }
    if mediatype != "multipart/form-data" {
        //...
    }
    boundary := p["boundary"]
    reader := multipart.NewReader(r.Body, boundary)
    buffer := make([]byte, 8192)
    for {
        part, err := reader.NextPart()
        if err != nil {
            // ... 
        }
    
        f, err := os.CreateTemp("", part.FileName())
        if err != nil {
            // ...
        }
    
        for {
            numBytesRead, err := part.Read(buffer)
            // People say not to read if there's an err, but then I miss the last chunk?
            f.Write(buffer[:numBytesRead])
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    break
                } else {
                    // error, abort ...
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in the innermost for loop, I found out that I have to read from part.Read before even checking for EOF, as I notice that I will miss the last chunk if I do so beforehand and break. However, I notice on many other articles/posts where people check for errors/EOF, and `break`-ing if there is without using the last read. Am I using multipart.Part.Read() wrongly/safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [multipart.Part](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.19.3#Part) in a proper way.

[multipart.Part](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.19.3#Part) is a [particular](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/mime/multipart/multipart.go;l=164) [implementation](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.19.3#Part.Read) of [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader). Accordingly, you should be guided by the conventions and follow the recommendations for [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader). Quote from the documentation:

> Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before considering the error err. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF behaviors.

---

Also note that in the example you are copying data from [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) to [os.File](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File). [os.File](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File) [implements](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.ReadFrom) [io.ReaderFrom](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderFrom) interface, so you can use [File.ReadFrom()](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.ReadFrom) method to copy the data.

```
_, err := file.ReadFrom(part)
// non io.EOF
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("copy data: %w", err)
}
```

---

If you need to use a buffer, you can use [io.CopyBuffer()](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyBuffer) function. But note that you need to hide [io.ReaderFrom](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderFrom) implementation, otherwise the buffer [will not be used](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/io/io.go;l=413) to perform the copy. See examples: [1](https://go.dev/play/p/j5kHtRl6tZZ), [2](https://go.dev/play/p/LJBDSNSPrJG), [3](https://go.dev/play/p/vKYC_mzmcGO).

```
_, err := io.CopyBuffer(writeFunc(file.Write), part, buffer)
// non io.EOF
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("copy data: %w", err)
}

type writeFunc func([]byte) (int, error)

func (write writeFunc) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
        return write(data)
}
```

---

Comment: Hmm I'm doing .Read() from a multipart.Part (https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Part.Read), not io.Reader? Or do they follow the same rules?

Comment: I clarified the answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Ah, it took me a while to see that the `r` in `p.r` in `Part.Read()` is an `io.Reader`. Thanks!

Comment: No, multipart.Part is [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) because it [possesses](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.19.3#Part.Read) the necessary method - `Read([]byte) (int, error)`. _Interfaces_ are **satisfied implicitly** in Go.  
I should make an addition to my answer. In the meantime, you can read [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#interfaces_and_types) and go through ["Tour of Go"](https://go.dev/tour/methods/9). Let me also mention the book "The Go Programming Language" by Alan A. A. Donovan and Brian W. Kernighan, chapter 7 describes the interfaces.